# OpenOPC tag activation?

Tags: python, opc, dymola

I'm trying to use OpenOPC as a client to connect to an OPC server generated thanks to Dymola.

What I can't figure out is the way to read from a particular tag.

Some tags are available ('SimControl') and others are not ('ModelVariables') whereas those tags should be available after server Initialization.

Is there a way to activate tags in the same way that what is it done in Matrikon Explorer.

Here is the code that I used :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Fri Feb 06 09:48:09 2015
Simple test to connect to the Dymosim server generated with Dymola
"""

import os,sys
import time,OpenOPC

#%% Connexion to server
opcserv='Dymosim.OPCServer'

opc = OpenOPC.client()
opc.connect(opcserv)

#%% Tags description in a dictionnary form

# Following tags are for simulation control 
# and are available as soon as the client is connected to the server
root1='SimControl.'
l1=['Realtime','tScale',
'Initialize','Pause','Run','Stop',
'Delay','Initialized','Time','Status']
Sim={t:root1+t for t in l1}

# Following tags are for variables display during simulation.
# They should be available after the simulation was "Initialize"
root2='ModelVariables.'  # Available once the model has been initialized
v1=['heatCapacitor.port.T','heatCapacitor.port.Q_flow']
l2=['T','Q']
Var={k:root2+v for (k,v) in zip(l2,v1)}


#%% Simulation
# Initialization of the simulation
opc.write((Sim['Initialize'],True))

#%% Run the simulation
opc.write((Sim['Run'],True))

# Pause simulation after 2 s
time.sleep(2)
opc.write((Sim['Pause'],True)) 

#%% Read variables
opc.read(Sim['Time']) # OK
opc.read(Var['T'])       # Seems not accessible. Quality is bad
opc.list() # The 2 tags appear (SimControl and ModelVariables)

#%% Run the simulation until the end
opc.write((Sim['Run'],True))
```

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: I am no experienced in the OpenOPC, but I just like to explain one thing that caught my eye: Your comment "Seems not accessible. Quality is bad" may be a misunderstanding. When the OPC server does know the item requested, it returns an error. When it DOES know the item, it returns a value-timestamp-quality structure (where the quality may be e.g. Good or Bad). Therefore, if you do not get an error, but get something which has Bad quality, then the problem is not on your side - it is simply the data the server had returned for that item. It would likely return the same to any other OPC client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been able to find a workaround by using the `properties` method of OpenOPC.

The value and quality return by the method `properties` are not consistent with the `read` method.

It seems that the `properties` method return the right value (with good quality) whereas the `read` method does not.